# RaphaelJS: Remove flickering when hovering and moving element

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm pretty new at Raphael JS, and SVG in general. Currently I'm using SVG and Raphael on a map-functionality.

I'm having an issue with a hover effect which offsets the given element you hover with 10px. However, if you move your mouse slowly into the element the hoverIn and hoverOut will happen a bunch of times resulting in flickering.

I think I could resolve this by cloning the countries and leave it hidden and stationary, when hovering. I could do this I say, because the map contains hundreds of shapes...

What is the approach? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the element moves when you hover over it, which cause the hoverOut event. What do you want to happen with slow mouse movements? It moves once, stays moved until the mouse gets inside?

You need to set a variable on the element to show when it's been shifted 10px. Then you can do something like (pseudocode)

```
hoverIn() { 
    if (isShifted) {
        inWhenShifted = true  
    } else {
        // offset element
        isShifted = true
    } 

hoverOut() {
    if (isShifted) { 
         if (inWhenShifted) {
             // put element back
             isShifted = false
             inWhenShifted = false
         } else {
             // do nothing?, this is the case where the hoverOut fired 
             // because we moved the element
         }
    } else {
        // do nothing?, this is the case where we hoverOut again after shifting
        // the element back
    }
}
```